# Comma seperated values to SQL IN STATEMENT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If i have a comma separated list of values:

```
A1,B2,B3
```

How do i pass this into a variable and then form it into an SQL IN statement.

```
DECLARE @DATE AS VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @DATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Getdate(), 112)

--PRINT @DATE
DECLARE @TIME AS VARCHAR(50)

--PRINT TIME
SELECT @TIME = Replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Getdate(), 108), ':', '')

DECLARE @ID AS VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @ID = Replace(W0128001, 32322, 32323, 3232323, 2323232, ',', ',')

--PRINT @ID
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @QUERY = 'SELECT * INTO BACKUPTABLE_' + @DATE + @TIME
             + '
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID IN (' + '''' + @ID + ''')'

--EXEC @query
PRINT @QUERY
```

I have tried to do a replace above but i want it so that an end user can PASTE into the values and my script will take care of the commas and properly form it. It should also strip out the last commas from the end.

My output needs to read:

```
SELECT * INTO BACKUPTABLE_201606061503
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID IN ('W0128001','32322','32323','3232323','2323232')
```

Comment: Looks like you have the right idea, pretty much. I think you might need to enclose the query in parenthesis to keep SQL Server from thinking you're giving it the name of a SP, though (change to `EXEC(@query)`)

Comment: I didn't want to exec it until i was happy with the `PRINT`

Comment: Usually, people mistake a single value that contains a comma-delimited string with a comma-delimited list of values. However this doesn't seem to be the case here. Please note that Sql-Server 2008 supports table valued parameters which are superior to comma-delimited lists for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you *don't* surround it with single quotes:

```
SET @QUERY = 'SELECT * INTO BACKUPTABLE_' + @DATE + @TIME + '
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID IN (' + @ID + ')';
```

There are other ways to pass comma-delimited values to a SQL statement, including using a `split()` function or XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateBackupTable]
    @ID varchar(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(50)= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Getdate(), 112);
DECLARE @TIME VARCHAR(50) = Replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Getdate(), 108), ':', '')

    declare @xml xml,@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

    set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@ID,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

 SET @SQL = N' SELECT * INTO ' + QUOTENAME('BACKUPTABLE_' + @DATE + @TIME)
         +  N' from TableName '
         +  N' where ID IN (
                            select r.value(''.'',''varchar(max)'') as item
                            from @xml.nodes(''//root/r'') as records(r)
                            )' 

    exec sp_executesql @sql
                    , N'@ID varchar(100), @xml XML'
                    , @ID
                    , @Xml
END
```